# cURL error 6: Could not resolve host

Tags: libcurl, docker, dns, localhost

Boa tarde pessoal estou tentando realizar um teste de autenticação utilizando o *GuzzleHttp*, que por sua vez utiliza o *cURL* por baixo dos panos, sem nenhum mistério:

```
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        $response = $http->post('http://site.test/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '2',
                'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
                'username' => 'email@mail.com',
                'password' => 'senha',
                'scope' => '*',
            ],
        ]);

        dd($response);
```

mas retorna o erro:

`GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: site.test`

para criar o ambiente de desenvolvimento estou utilizando o **laradock** com os seguintes serviços:

> Creating laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ... done
>
> Creating laradock_mariadb_1          ... done
>
> Creating laradock_workspace_1        ... done
>
> Creating laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done
>
> Creating laradock_apache2_1          ... done

e meu arquivo **/etc/hosts** esta assim:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   thiago-340XAA-350XAA-550XAA
127.0.0.1   site.test

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Alguma boa alma pode me dizer o que estou errando?

Comment: **Solução** -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929097/10569196
**Causa** -- https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/435#issuecomment-261746807